# Android - tap image to have it scale, and optionally rotate, to fill screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a scroll view that contains ImageViews. I want the user to be able to tap on one of those images to animate it to scale up to fill the entire screen (except status bar at the top). If the image has a landscape ratio, I want the image to rotate 90 degrees during the animation. The images within the scroll view are not cropped, but once they're scaled up I'll want to crop the images to fill the available screen.

I have made an attempt which appends a second ImageView directly over the original. This new view overrides the `onDraw` method to handle the rotation with `canvas.rotate(rotation, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);`, then a custom Animation class which does the scaling by calculating new LayoutParams. It works for portrait images and almost works for the landscape ones, but scales them too much.

I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the bounds of the ImageView and the underlying Canvas that I'm rotating. Note that I'm targeting Android 2.2, otherwise I would use the `view.setRotation()` methods.

Here's some code:

```
public class ImageZoom extends ImageView
{
  float rotation = 0;

  // Constructors here...

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    if(rotation != 0)
    {
      canvas.rotate(rotation, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

And the animation:

```
public class ImageZoomAnimation extends Animation {
    public ImageZoomAnimation(View view, View parent) {
        this.view = (ImageZoom)view;
        this.parent = parent;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams initParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        this.startWidth = initParams.width;
        this.startHeight = initParams.height;
        isRotate = startWidth > startHeight;
        this.startLeftMargin = initParams.leftMargin;
        this.startTopMargin = initParams.topMargin;;
        this.endWidth = parent.getWidth();
        this.endHeight = parent.getHeight();
        this.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        this.setDuration(2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth = (int) (startWidth + ((endWidth - startWidth) * interpolatedTime));
        int newHeight = (int) (startHeight + ((endHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
        params.leftMargin = (int)(startLeftMargin * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        params.topMargin = (int)(startTopMargin * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        if(isRotate)
        {
            view.setRotation(90 * interpolatedTime);
        }
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way. Having the canvas rotating in one class and mucking around with the layout parameters in another seems wrong. Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Wow, this was really hard. I managed it, but I still wonder if it couldn't have been better. If you come across this issue and you really want the answer, let me know.

Comment: Definitely interested. Basically I have a gridview of images, and want to click one to get it to exactly as you describe, it's not trivial

Comment: Please post your answer, interested in this.